# How are non linear games built computationally?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, class-structure

I'm really interested in non-linear games and have taken up programming to learn to build them. So far, I've learned of basic data structures, algorithms, design patterns and a couple languages. But I'm really interested in what data structures, or general programming constructs, with narrative techniques are used for non linear games such as Mass Effect, The Witcher series and even upcoming titles like Quantic Dream's Detroit: Become Human? I truly believe games like these are what will really solidify interactive entertainment as a medium.

Comment: You should ask this at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, though if you focus the question to be just about the narrative techniques, it might be on-topic here.

Comment: The answer is [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). Also [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) on the conceptual side of things.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, games like these mesh the story telling idea with the game engine to allow players to move through the story. This is somewhat analogous to making a movie, first you need a script or story, then the various artists, craft and trades people to translate the elements of the story to the screen.

Teaching "narrative" or storytelling is something of an artform in of itself, and being a good storyteller is not sufficient, you also have to understand the medium.

A good example is the movie ["Gettysburg"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107007/). The source material is the civil war novel "T[he Killer Angels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345348109)", by Michael Sharra, widely considered to be one of "the" great American Civil War novels. The people who bought the movie rights were obviously in love with the book, so much so they created a movie which is practically a word for word recreation of the book. Sadly, what works on the page does not translate well on the screen, and while there are some [amazing scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d2_zeJTJcw) in the movie, overall it does not flow well.

Stanley Kubrick considered the key difference between movies and other forms of art was the ability to edit movies, and much of the real magic on the movie making process is editing the scenes together, finding the right "take" and even how you order scenes. (Christopher Nolan's movie "[Memento](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)" is actually told "back to front", but in a different universe, he could have edited all the scenes together to make the story linear).

So knowing the mechanics of how games systems work and how players interact with the game is much like being one of the people who craft the film (cinematography, sound, lighting, special effects, crafts etc.), none of that works without a compelling story and a director and editor who can translate the story into the specific patterns that the media needs to make it work.